# Синхронизация потоков. Блокировать только при записи

Tags: java, многопоточность, синхронизация

Много где видел синхронизацию потоков. Обычно она связана с неким общим ресурсом. Но вот не натыкался ни разу на нюанс. Как сделать так, чтобы если нет ни одной операции записи синхронизации как бы не было вообще, то есть объект могут читать сразу куча потоков. Но только когда начинается запись, все замирают в ожидании финала записи, точно так же как и запись ожидает финала чтения.

Например в java блок synchronized решает эту задачу частично. Когда будет `synchronized read()` он заблокирует не только `synchronized write()` но и все другие вызову `read()`, верно? Есть ли возможность этого избежать и дать возможность вызывать чтение сколько угодно раз до тех пор, пока не будет вызвана запись?

То есть чтение - много потоков, запись - один?

Comment: Общий ресурс в вашем контексте это что? БД или что-то другое?

Comment: Да что угодно, общий ресурс это обычно просто термин для обозначения "объект, который нужно синхронизировать", то есть то, к чему пытаются получить доступ несколько потоков. Это может быть и просто счетчик в оперативной памяти в принципе.

Comment: Просто в случае с БД это реализуется по другому, средствами самой БД, которой можно управлять при коннекте с ним

Comment: БД уже синхронизирован за вас ) Если вы будете писать свою БД, вам придется предусмотреть синхронизацию.

Comment: Ладно, похоже мы не понимаем друг-друга, оставим это :)

Answer (score 3):

Для этого существует интерфейс [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) и его реализация [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html).

Пример из [данного ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10372683):

```
class Store
{
    private ReadWriteLock rwlock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    public void write()
    {
       rwlock.writeLock().lock();
       try {
          //запись
       } finally {
          rwlock.writeLock().unlock();
       }
    }

    public String read()
    {
       rwlock.readLock().lock();
       try {
          //чтение
       } finally {
          rwlock.readLock().unlock();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Интересно, как он внутри реализуется. Это что-то на основе стандартных средств Java или же Native?

Comment: @Uraty посмотрел немного исходный код класса `ReentrantReadWriteLock` - разобраться в куче кода, абстракций и их реализаций достаточно проблемно. `native` методов я в классе не нашел.

Comment: Вот и я тоже решил заглянуть внутрь, тоже native не нашел. Но всё закручено на AbstractQueuedSynchronizer. Внутри что-то с счетчиком мутится. Тоже не въехал особо )

Comment: @Uraty да, и кода в `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` ещё больше. Поэтому остаётся только верить документации (тем более что это не сторонняя реализация) и опыту использования. В конце концов, если нужна реализация множественного неблокирующего чтения и блокирующей записи - то вот, есть такое, и главное уметь им корректно пользоваться.

Comment: По идее, легко соорудить вручную из обыкновенного `Lock`'а и `condition variable`.

Comment: @VladD да, как-то оно так представляется, но немалое количество строк кода говорит, что, видимо, не всё так просто. Хотя я так и не разбирался с исходным кодом этого дела. Да и изобретать свой велосипед в такой ситуации, думаю, смысла нет.

Comment: @Regent: Немалое количество строк кода, наверное, для подключения стратегий/dependency injection/повторного использования и тому подобного. Если имплементировать вручную, по идее будет проще.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужен, судя по всему, `ReadWriteLock` ([вот](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html)).

Он позволяет заблокировать эксклюзивно для записи, или заблокировать неэксклюзивно для чтения. То есть в каждый момент времени будет доступ либо у (всех) читателей, либо у (одного) писателя.